# Oracle query for first sunday

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle query which returns next month first Sunday. Now I have a condition here to check if the next month is having 1st day as Sunday then it needs to return next Sunday. Else, next month's first sunday.

My query:

```
DEF  startDate = to_date('somedate', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
Select next_day(last_day(&startDate),'Sunday' )  from dual ;
```

Expected output: if we input july 2018, it has to return 5th August 2018(first sunday). if it is june 2018, then it has to return july 8th (not 1st july whic is first day and its sunday)

```
Input      Expected Output
   Jul-18   05-Aug-18,
   Aug-18   02-sep-18,
  June-18   08-jul-18,
```

because 1st day is sunday, so we are considering next Sunday 8th July.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51441726/266304)?

Comment: Our inputs were only month and year. logic here is, if i give any month and year, it has to return next month first sunday and if the next month first day is sunday, then we need second sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date you pass in to `next_day()` is already the first Sunday you'll get the second Sunday, so pass in the first day of next month. You can get that by finding the first of the current month and adding a month; or by finding the last day of the current month and adding a day:

```
with cte (start_date) as (
            select date '2018-05-14' from dual
  union all select date '2018-06-15' from dual
  union all select date '2018-07-16' from dual
  union all select date '2018-08-17' from dual
)
select start_date,
  next_day(add_months(trunc(start_date, 'MM'), 1), 'Sunday') as result1,
  next_day(trunc(start_date, 'MM') + interval '1' month, 'Sunday') as result2,
  next_day(last_day(start_date) + 1, 'Sunday') as result3
from cte;

START_DATE RESULT1    RESULT2    RESULT3   
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2018-05-14 2018-06-03 2018-06-03 2018-06-03
2018-06-15 2018-07-08 2018-07-08 2018-07-08
2018-07-16 2018-08-05 2018-08-05 2018-08-05
2018-08-17 2018-09-02 2018-09-02 2018-09-02
```

If the 'start date' is always going to be the first of the month then you don't need the `trunc(..., 'MM')` part; that takes any day in the month and returns midnight on the 1st of that month.

Comment: I have created this query:                                                                                     
DEF  startDate = to_date('11/2018', 'mm/yyyy');
select &startDate,
  next_day(add_months(trunc(&startDate, 'MM'), 1), 'Sunday') as result1,
  next_day(trunc(&startDate, 'MM') + interval '1' month, 'Sunday') as result2,
  next_day(last_day(&startDate) + 1, 'Sunday') as result3
from dual;                                                                         
 can we embed this in a function? and it has to take the month and year and return the result as above

Comment: Sure, you can create a function to do that if you're going to be doing the same thing in many places.You don't need to select from dual then, just return the `next_day()` directly.

Comment: Could you please help me in creating a function?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use below Oracle Query to get first Sunday of the current month

`SELECT DECODE(TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 'DAY')), 'SUNDAY', (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), NEXT_DAY((TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 'SUNDAY')) FROM DUAL`