# Function Created with compilation errors in Oracle with table / view doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have created a function which is working on my local but giving compilation error while creating on specific user and schema.

I have verified the tables and this function executed in my local machine and returning the values. but when I tried to log in to other user and tries to create the function, it's giving compilation error.

```
`/*Get_Accountdetails Functions*/
 create or replace function Get_Accountdetails(inpstr1 in 
 varchar2,inpstr2 in varchar2) return get_acnt_type
 as
v_ret   get_acnt_type;   
a  dbms_utility.uncl_array;
b  dbms_utility.uncl_array; 
len1  pls_integer;  
len2  pls_integer;  
cnt pls_integer :=1;
inp_str1 varchar(32000) := regexp_replace(inpstr1,'[][]','"');
inp_str2 varchar(32000) := regexp_replace(inpstr2,'[][]','"');
inp_str3 varchar(32000) := replace(inp_str2,'"."','","');
inp_val1 varchar(320):= '';
inp_val2 varchar(320):= '';
out_acval1 varchar(320):= '';
out_aclval2 varchar(320):= '';
out_dbval3 varchar(320):= '';
v_aid varchar2(10);
v_db_id  varchar2(10);
v_lvl_id varchar2(10);
sa_user_code  varchar2(100);    
count1 pls_integer;  

begin
v_ret  := get_acnt_type();     
dbms_utility.comma_to_table(inp_str1, len1, a); 
dbms_utility.comma_to_table(inp_str3, len2, b);

for j in 1..len2/2 loop
    sa_user_code := replace(b(cnt),'"','');  
    for i in 1..len1 loop                                 
        inp_val1 := a(i);                               
        v_aid := regexp_substr(inp_val1, '\d+', 1, 1);
        v_db_id  := regexp_substr(inp_val1, '\d+', 1, 2);
        v_lvl_id := regexp_substr(inp_val1, '\d+', 1, 3);

        IF v_lvl_id = '1' THEN
            SELECT COUNT(*)into count1
            from gdw.dim_cust_acnt                      
            where RCL_LVL_1_ACNT_ID = v_aid and RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id AND ROWNUM=1;       

        ELSE IF v_lvl_id = '2' THEN
            SELECT COUNT(*)into count1
            from gdw.dim_cust_DEPT                      
            where RCL_LVL_2_ACNT_ID = v_aid and RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id AND ROWNUM=1; 
        ELSE
            SELECT COUNT(*)into count1
            from gdw.dim_cust_dept                      
            where RCL_LVL_3_ACNT_ID = v_aid and RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id AND ROWNUM=1;
        END IF;
        END IF;

        IF count1 > 0 THEN
            IF(UPPER (sa_user_code) = 'SA') THEN                           
                CASE v_lvl_id

                    when 1 then --If Level 1 then check GDW.Dim_Cust_Acnt                     
                    select dim_cust_key,RCL_LVL_1_ACNT_ID,RCL_SRC_DB_ID into out_acval1,out_aclval2,out_dbval3 from gdw.dim_cust_acnt                                   
                    where RCL_LVL_1_ACNT_ID = v_aid and RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id AND ROWNUM=1;

                    when 2 then  --If Level 2  then check GDW.Dim_Cust_Dept
                    select dim_cust_dept_key,RCL_LVL_2_ACNT_ID,RCL_SRC_DB_ID into out_acval1,out_aclval2,out_dbval3 from gdw.dim_cust_dept                   
                    where RCL_LVL_2_ACNT_ID = v_aid and RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id AND ROWNUM=1;

                    else --If Level 3 then check GDW.Dim_Cust_Dept
                     select dim_cust_dept_key,RCL_LVL_3_ACNT_ID,RCL_SRC_DB_ID into out_acval1,out_aclval2,out_dbval3 from gdw.dim_cust_dept 
                     where RCL_LVL_3_ACNT_ID = v_aid and RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id AND ROWNUM=1;

                END CASE; 

                v_ret.extend; 
                v_ret(v_ret.count) := Get_acnt_obj(out_acval1,out_aclval2,out_dbval3,v_lvl_id);

            ELSE
                CASE v_lvl_id--If Level 1 then check GDW.Dim_Cust_Acnt
                    when 1 then 
                        select dca.dim_cust_key,dca.RCL_LVL_1_ACNT_ID,dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID into out_acval1,out_aclval2,out_dbval3 from gdw.dim_cust_acnt dca
                        INNER JOIN bi_rpt.dtl_usr_acnt_scrty fc ON fc.SRC_DB_ID =dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID 
                        AND fc.acnt_cd=dca.CUST_ID
                        where dca.RCL_LVL_1_ACNT_ID = v_aid and dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id and fc.SRC_USR_CD=sa_user_code AND ROWNUM=1;          

                    when 2 then --If Level 3 then check GDW.Dim_Cust_Dept
                        select dca.dim_cust_dept_key,dca.RCL_LVL_2_ACNT_ID,dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID into out_acval1,out_aclval2,out_dbval3 from gdw.dim_cust_dept dca                              
                        INNER JOIN bi_rpt.dtl_usr_acnt_scrty fc  ON fc.SRC_DB_ID =dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID 
                        AND fc.ACNT_LVL_1_CD=dca.CUST_DIV_CD
                        where dca.RCL_LVL_2_ACNT_ID = v_aid and dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id and fc.SRC_USR_CD=sa_user_code AND ROWNUM=1;                    
                    else --If Level  3 then check GDW.Dim_Cust_Dept
                        select dca.dim_cust_dept_key,dca.RCL_LVL_3_ACNT_ID,dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID into out_acval1,out_aclval2,out_dbval3 from gdw.dim_cust_dept DCA                             
                        INNER JOIN bi_rpt.dtl_usr_acnt_scrty fc  ON fc.SRC_DB_ID =dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID 
                        AND fc.ACNT_LVL_2_CD=dca.CUST_DEPT_CD
                        where dca.RCL_LVL_3_ACNT_ID = v_aid and dca.RCL_SRC_DB_ID = v_db_id and fc.SRC_USR_CD=sa_user_code AND ROWNUM=1;                      
                END CASE; 
                v_ret.extend; 
                v_ret(v_ret.count) := Get_acnt_obj(out_acval1,out_aclval2,out_dbval3,v_lvl_id);

            End IF;

        ELSE
            CONTINUE;
        END IF;     
    END LOOP; 
    cnt := cnt+2;       
END LOOP;
return v_ret;
END;
 /
```

object Type which I have created in working fine.

```
/
/* Define the structure of the object that is returned from function 
Get_AccountDetails*/
create or replace type Get_acnt_obj as object (

 dim_cust_key number,

 level_account_id number,

 database_id number,

 level_number number

 );
 /



 /* Inserting the data into the object that returned from function 
 Get_AccountDetails*/
 create or replace type get_acnt_type as table of Get_acnt_obj;
```

This type function is succesfully created on any user.

Comment: Maybe issues in privileges ? anyway what are the compilation errors?

Comment: Has `gdw` granted privileges on its objects directly to the user creating the function?

Comment: yeah, they granted all the privileges to create a function.

Comment: Error:[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
38/26   PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Not the privileges to create a function; `select` privileges on the `gdw.*` (and `bi_rpt.*`) tables being referenced by the function. And they need to be granted directly to the user creating the function, not via a role.

Comment: ..when I tried to log in to other user ..  did all tables/views get verified as this other user ?